# Java's regex confusion

Tags: java, regex

Basically i want to match filename with .json extension but not file that start with . and excluding list.json.

This is what i come out with (without java string escapes)

```
(?i)^([^\.][^list].+|list.+)\.json$
```

I had use an online regex tester, Regexplanet to try my regex
http://fiddle.re/x9g86

Everything works fine with the regex tester, however when i tried it in Java. Everything that has the letter l,i,s,t will be excluded... which is very confusing for me.

Can anyone give me some clues?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a character exclusion class, `[^list]`, which ignores character order and instead of excluding `list`, excludes any cases of `l`, `i`, `s`, or `t`.

Instead, you want to use a negative lookahead:

```
(?i)(?!^list\.json$)[^\.].*\.json
```

Comment: I think it should be `(?i)(?!list\.json$)...`, because it seems like `list.json.json` or similar should match.

Comment: `list.list.json` and similar are valid filenames according to the question's guidelines, and match successfully.

Comment: Not `list.list.json`, rather `list.json.json`. [It doesn't match](http://ideone.com/d9HTm0). The question appears to say it should exclude a string only if it is `list.json`, not if it simply starts with it.

Comment: My bad, I misread your first comment. I've edited the regex to only exclude `list.json` rather than strings starting with `list.json`, thanks.  I do believe that your regex is cleaner however.

Answer (score 8):

> I want to match filename with `.json` extension but not file that start with `.` and excluding `list.json`.

I am not sure you need regular expressions for this. I find the following much easier on the eye:

```
boolean match = s.endsWith(".json") && !s.startsWith(".") && !s.equals("list.json");
```

Comment: Thanks, it is just me trying to be stubborn lol. I still wish to know why my regular expressions doesn't work though...

Comment: @megablue I've undeleted my answer, which explains why your regex doesn't work as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

A negative look-ahead will do it.

```
(?i)(?!\.|list\.json$).*\.json
```

`(?!\.|list\.json$)` is a negative look-ahead checking that the characters following is not either `list.json` followed by the end of the string, or `.`.

Code:

```
String regex = "(?i)(?!\\.|list\\.json$).*\\.json";
System.out.println("list.json".matches(regex)); // false
System.out.println(".json".matches(regex));     // false
System.out.println("a.Json".matches(regex));    // true
System.out.println("abc.json".matches(regex));  // true
```

But NPE's more readable solution is probably preferred.

Comment: i was looking at negative look-ahead but couldn't figure out how to use it probably. Thanks!!!